# document.write to current HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid, document.write

I am a noob to programming, so I'd appreciate any advice from you more knowledgeable folks out there. I am working on a bit of javascript for a web page and I need the javascript to print to that current HTML page, preferably in the div tag I have set up for that purpose. Here's what I have so far:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Tardy Reporting</title>
<script src="students.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Scan in Student ID</h1>
<form method="POST" name="idForm" onSubmit="getId(parseInt(document.idForm.studentId.value));">
<input type="text" name="studentId" id="studentId"/>
<input type="Submit" name="Submit" />
</form>
<div id="div1"></div>
<p>
</body>
</html>
```

and my JS file:

```
var studentNumberArray = [50011234, 50012345, 50013456];
var studentNameArray = ["Mike Simpson", "Greg Pollard", "Jason Vigil"];
var studentLastPeriodArray = ["George Washington", "Darth Vadar", "Obi Wan Kenobi"];
var tardyArray = [0, 0, 0];

function getId(studentId) {
  for (i = 0; i < studentNumberArray.length; i++){
    if(studentId === studentNumberArray[i]){   
          tardyArray[i] += tardyArray[i] + 1;
            document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='test';
      }
    }
}
```

Mind you, this is just the basic framework, so it's not nearly done yet, but the thing that is bugging me is that it'll go through the code correctly and print it out, but the result only lasts a fraction of a second on my browsers (chromium and firefox). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean it only lasts for a second?

Comment: The reason is because you're using a form to submit. This causes the page to refresh after submitting. So the "lasts a second" is because it displays what you want, then submits, then refreshes. A combination of using Kory's and Sofian's answers should help out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an easier/better way to accomplish what you are trying to do

```
var students = {};

// Add students to object
students[50011234] = { 'id': '50011234', 'name':"Mike Simpson", 'lastPeriod':"George Washington", 'tardy':0 };
students[50012345] = { 'id': '50012345', 'name':"Greg Pollard", 'lastPeriod':"Darth Vadar", 'tardy':0 };
students[50013456] = { 'id': '50013456', 'name':"Jason Vigil", 'lastPeriod':"Obi Wan Kenobi", 'tardy':0 };


function getId(studentId) {

  students[ studentId ].tardy += 1;
  document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='test';
}
```

Also, as pointed out below, you should change your button to not submit if that is not what you are intending to happen:

```
<form method="POST" name="idForm">
    <input type="text" name="studentId" id="studentId"/>
    <input type="button" onclick="getId(parseInt(document.idForm.studentId.value));" name="Mark Tardy" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you see it only for a fraction of a second is that you are actually causing a submit. A submit is a full call back to the server which returns the page to its initial status. 
To fix this simply make the function call on the onclick event of the button:

```
<html>
<head><title>Tardy Reporting</title>
    <script src="students.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Scan in Student ID</h1>
    <form method="POST" name="idForm" >
    <input type="text" name="studentId" id="studentId" />
    <input type="button" onclick="getId(parseInt(document.idForm.studentId.value));" value="submit"  />
    </form>
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "result"? It appears that you are setting the `innerHTML` of `div1` to "test" over and over again.

Perhaps you mean to write

```
document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML += 'test';
```

Doing this is not efficient and it is preferable you concatenate on a string, or even better, join an array, before assigning the `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0):

**`Forms` are a special construct that allows communication with a server:**

- When a form is submitted, the form data is "POSTED" to a server via an HTTP request.
- Typically, the browser displays the server's response as a new web page.
- Forms use the `action` attribute to specify which server page  should process the request
- *In your case, no `action` is specified, so the form POSTS to the current page, which is equivalent to refreshing the page.* This means that all client-side (JavaScript) changes are wiped out, which is why you only see them for a split-second.

**To achieve your desired result, change the input type from `submit` to `button`:**

```
<input type="button" onclick=".." value="submit"  />
```

Ideally, the student data exists in a database that is manipulated by code on a server. Your form would POST a request that returns an HTML page containing the desired data.

**References**

- [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTTP)
- [Forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/form)

Answer (score 0):

> > but the result only lasts a fraction of a second on my browsers (chromium and firefox).

That is because you are submitting the page, so the page gets refreshed. You need to change the button type to button from submit. Also add a onclick to the button and call the js function getId